# Checking each URL works in tests on a Yesod site

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, yesod, hspec

I was trying to check that all links work on a Yesod website home page. I wrote this hSpec test.

```
module Handler.HomeSpec (spec) where

import           Data.Either                (fromRight)
import qualified Data.Text                  as T
import           Network.Wai.Test           (simpleBody)
import           TestImport
import           Yesod.Test.TransversingCSS (findAttributeBySelector)

getAllLinks :: YesodExample site [Text]
getAllLinks = withResponse $ \res -> do
    let links = fromRight [] findAttributeBySelector (simpleBody res) "a" "href"
    return $ T.concat <$> links

spec :: Spec
spec = withApp $
    describe "Homepage" $ do
        it "checks all links" $ do
            get HomeR
            statusIs 200
            links <- getAllLinks

            forM_ links $ \oneLink -> do
                get HomeR
                statusIs 200
                get oneLink
                statusIs 200
```

Everything compiles ok but the `get` function gets rid of the host part of the URLs you feed it. For example, when you give it `https://github.com/zigazou/bazasso`, it will try to fetch `/zigazou/bazasso` which returns a 404 code.

Is there a way to make it work like I want ?

Should I add a function that removes external links from the tests ?

Is it simply not the right place to do it ?

Comment: I think that it is bug of yesod-test, I will write pull request or issue.

Comment: It seems that yesod-test is not a bug because it does not make an actual http request using runSession.
It's confusing to see Google in the sample code.
I think that the case of an external request for the time being there is a workaround to use the hspec of http-conduit and iodine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpler, the better: I've removed everything that starts with a protocol from the links that will be checked. Thanks to @ncaq for your comments.

```
module Handler.HomeSpec (spec) where

import           Data.Either                (fromRight)
import qualified Data.Text                  as T
import           Network.Wai.Test           (simpleBody)
import           TestImport
import           Yesod.Test.TransversingCSS (findAttributeBySelector)

isRelative :: Text -> Bool
isRelative url
    | T.take 7 url == "http://"  = False
    | T.take 8 url == "https://" = False
    | T.take 7 url == "mailto:"  = False
    | T.take 4 url == "tel:"     = False
    | otherwise                  = True

getAllLinks :: YesodExample site [Text]
getAllLinks = withResponse $ \res -> do
    let currentHtml = simpleBody res
        links = fromRight [] $ findAttributeBySelector currentHtml "a" "href"
    return $ filter isRelative $ T.concat <$> links

spec :: Spec
spec = withApp $
    describe "Homepage" $ do
        it "checks all links" $ do
            get HomeR
            statusIs 200
            links <- getAllLinks

            forM_ links $ \oneLink -> do
                get HomeR
                statusIs 200
                get oneLink
                statusIs 200
```